# grub2-mkconfig is taking fedora path instead of centos while installing centos7 via kickstart file and in UEFI mode

Tags: installation, centos7, bootloader

I am trying to install centos7 ISO using kickstart and ISO installation is working fine but during post installation setup procedure getting error when installing Bootloader.

BootLoaderError: failed to write boot loader configuration

Log shows,

efibootmgr -c -w -L CentOS 7 -d /dev/sda -p 1 -l \EFI\fedora\shimx64.efi
..
..
.
.
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg
/sbin/grub2-mkconfig : line 244: /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg.new: No such file or directory

Any pointers why it is taking fedora inside the efibootmgr path and grub-mkconfig path. It should take centos instead of fedora.
I already checked that there is directory of centos at path /boot/efi/EFI/centos/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Still stuck with this problem. Any pointers about how to solve above issue

Comment: Finally able to resolve the issue,

It was due to hard coded check inside Anaconda installclass - if productName.startswith("CentOS ")

In my case, the product name was not starting with CentOS hence it was taking default value of efi_dir = fedora